# How to count occurrences of all the words in all the files of a directory using grep? But with count incremented only once per word per file

Tags: bash, files, grep, directory

I have already asked a similar question but people misunderstood what i was asking. I was asking how to generate a list of every word with a word count incremented only once per word per file.

For example, I have a directory with 10 files , I want to generate a list of words using bash commands which says a value of 1-10 depending on how many files they appear in:

```
10 The
10 and
8 bash
7 command
6 help....
```

etc.

I already know that `grep -l word *| wc -l` will search for a single word but I want to create a list of all words.

Is there a way to combine that with `tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]' | tr -d '[:punct:]'` so that words with capital letters aren't duplicated and punctuation is removed?

Comment: Instead of cross posting questions[1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27369047/bash-code-word-occurance-counting-within-a-directory-of-texts) and [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27426826/how-to-count-occurrences-of-all-the-words-in-all-the-files-of-a-directory-but-w) please edit your question and make it clear.

Comment: Sorry but this is the only way I know how to explain it, I don't know how i can make it clearer. I'm looking for something that can count, not how many times the word occurs in a directory but how many files it occurs in.

Comment: So none of the given answers worked for you? 7 answers

Comment: Nope, unfortunately not, i've tried clarifying it to the people who have tried answering it but to no avail

Comment: You can provide a simple example of content of each file(not real data but similar to real) for example for 5 file and then with a sample of your output from all 5 or as you says 10 files.

Comment: Why "using grep"? Have you considered, for example, `awk`?

Answer (score 2):

I'd use perl here:

```
perl -T -lne '
  for (/\w+/g) {$count{lc $_}->{$ARGV}=undef}
  END {print "$_: " . keys %{$count{$_}} for keys %count}' ./*
```

That constructs a hash of hash `$count{word}` is a reference to a hash whose keys are the names of the files that `word` is found in (and values we don't care, here set to `undef`).

In the end, we just count the number of elements (so number of files) for each of those hashes (so for each of the found words).

Answer (score 1):

I just came across the original [answer here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/174178/29168) by @Mehmet while searching for something unrelated and I see that although it works, it is horribly inefficient, requiring each file to be read again for each unique word in all of the files!  The second answer by @Jeff is rather convoluted despite the explanation and worst of all it suffers from the `cat file |` sin!

A single pass on all the data is all that is required and it can be formulated by effectively combining the earlier answers:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print |
while read file; do
    egrep -h -o "[[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]_-]*" "$file" |
    tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]' |
    sed "s|^|$file\||"
done |
sort -t '|' -k 2 |
uniq |
awk -F '|' '{
    if (lw != $2) {
        print fc " " lw;
        fc = 0;
    }
    lw = $2;
    fc++;
}'
```

Note the choice of field separator is important if your filenames include paths, and/or if they include spaces.  I chose the `|` character since it should never be part of a word printed by `egrep` and it is unlikely to ever appear in a file or directory name.

Answer (score -1):

This should get all the words from all the files, sort them and get unique words, than iterate through those words and count how many files it occurs in.

```
# find all words from all files within the directory
grep -o -h -E '\w+' directory/*|sort -u | \
while read word;
do
        # iterate through each word and find how many files it occurs
        c=`grep -l "$word" directory/*|wc -l`
        echo "$c $word";
done
```

Comment: Yes that works for all word occurrences but i'm looking for occurrence PER FILE. So each word has a number next to it stating how many files it appears in, not how many times it occurs in those files

Comment: I see @Cnvrsn I updated it, take a look.

Answer (score -1):

This is how to process each file in a directory individually:

```
for f in yourdirectory/*; do cat "$f" |
```

This is how I filter out everything but words from text data:

```
sed 's/\.$//;s/\.\([^0-9]\)/\1/g;s/[][(),;:?!]//g' | tr [A-Z] [a-z] |
```

But your method may work just as well. (I wanted to make sure not to remove hyphens from hyphenated words, nor apostrophes from contractions.)

Either way, continue as follows:

```
tr -s ' ' '\012' | sort -u ; done |
```

This makes a one-per-file list of words, so now just:

```
sort | uniq -c
```

If you want the list from most- to least-frequent, just tack on `|sort -nr`.

You may also need to add some additional punctuation, such as `{}` to the list at the end of the `sed` above, depending on your input data.

Comment: Congratulations, you win a [UUOC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#Useless_use_of_cat).

Comment: Yeah, I know, but it made the possible substitution of OP code (for the second block) less fraught.