# grep with count of individual patterns

Tags: shell-script, grep, wc

I have a file with MAC addresses (1/line with : as separator, sorted) and I need to find out how many times each of these MAC addresses appears in the file. I modified this:

[How to count occurrences of all the words in all the files of a directory using grep? But with count incremented only once per word per file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/174167/how-to-count-occurrences-of-all-the-words-in-all-the-files-of-a-directory-using)

... a bit to get this:

```
#!/bin/sh

grep -o -h -E '\w+' macadd | sort -u | \
while read word;
do
        # iterate through each word and find how many files it occurs
        c=`grep "$word" macadd | wc -l`
        echo "$c    $word";
done
```

Which produces this output:

```
$ ./test.sh
12    00
84    08
6    09
36    0A
84    0B
1415    0C
4    10
6    12
68    13
```

... which is obviously isn't what I'm looking for. When I remove : from the source file, I get this:

```
6    00EEBDA24AE1
3    10AE605A727A
6    2847AAC81C88
2    34C059B368DC
10    4C3C1655CD6A
1415    4C7F62310CD0
1    50CCF8BA10D7
```

... which gives me what I want, but I'd like to retain the : separator for various reasons. It'd be also nice to have the width of the first column standard to produce a table output:

```
6    00:EE:BD:A2:4A:E1
3    10:AE:60:5A:72:7A
6    28:47:AA:C8:1C:88
2    34:C0:59:B3:68:DC
10   4C:3C:16:55:CD:6A
1415 4C:7F:62:31:0C:D0
1    50:CC:F8:BA:10:D7
```

Where to go from here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It sounds like you are reinventing `uniq -c`

Comment: AAARRRGGGHHH!!! :D I was indeed, thanks :) If you'd be kind to make that an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
sort macadd | uniq -c
```

Answer (score 3):

All you need is `sort macadd | uniq -c` as explained by @roaima but I just wanted to point out how you could do it using the same approach you had attempted.

There's no reason to `grep` through the file, you can just feed it directly to `while`:

```
while read mac; do echo "$mac"; done < macadd
```

Also, `grep` has a `-c` option which counts matches. So, with a couple of small tweaks, you can do what you were attempting using the tools you were using:

```
$ while read mac; do 
    printf "%5s\t%s\n" $(grep -c "$mac" macadd) "$mac"; 
  done < <(sort -u macadd)
   6     00:EE:BD:A2:4A:E1
   3     10:AE:60:5A:72:7A
   6     28:47:AA:C8:1C:88
   2     34:C0:59:B3:68:DC
  10     4C:3C:16:55:CD:6A
1415     4C:7F:62:31:0C:D0
   1     50:CC:F8:BA:10:D7
```

Now, your `grep` was failing because `:` is not considered a word-character,  so is not matched by `\w`. You could instead have used something like this:

```
grep -ohE '[A-Z0-9:]+' macadd | sort -u
```

But there's no need for `grep` since `sort` can do it by itself (always assuming that your file has nothing but MAC addresses):

```
sort -u macadd | while read . . .
```